# JSON path for getting total number records in its response

Tags: json, soap, wso2, jsonpath, wso2-esb

I’m working with wso2esb 4.9.0 and Wso2dss3.0.0

I have a SOAP response from a DSS service as shown below

```
 <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DataCollection xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <Datalist>
            <partybranchid>2127629166052452</partybranchid>
            <partybranchname>other locations</partybranchname>
            <status>1</status>
            <partybranchtype>-1</partybranchtype>
            <partyid>460077453499443</partyid>
            <partyname>Yash Technologies Pvt Ltd</partyname>
            <ouid>-1</ouid>
            <organizationunitname>NONE</organizationunitname>
            <inchargeid>-1899999899</inchargeid>
            <sbuheadid>-1</sbuheadid>
            <usercriteriaconfigid>1187416899913503</usercriteriaconfigid>
            <primarymail>vikash@myunisoft.com</primarymail>
         </Datalist>
         <Datalist>
            <partybranchid>2545910581364239</partybranchid>
            <partybranchname>DBPB001</partybranchname>
            <status>1</status>
            <partybranchtype>2299733851146138</partybranchtype>
            <partyid>2534954639984412</partyid>
            <partyname>DBPRTY001</partyname>
            <ouid>2538210579514587</ouid>
            <organizationunitname>DBORG001</organizationunitname>
            <inchargeid>2540093122446574</inchargeid>
            <sbuheadid>1209449655666077</sbuheadid>
            <usercriteriaconfigid>1187416899913503</usercriteriaconfigid>
            <primarymail>vikash@myunisoft.com</primarymail>
         </Datalist>
      </DataCollection>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

From the above SOAP response, Iwant to get the total number of `Datalist` records in to my  service. For this I have given a JSON property document as shown below:

```
<property name="Total"
             expression="json-eval($.DataCollection.Datalist.length)"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
```

`Total` should get the value as `2`, because they are two records, as you can see; but this is instead returning `null`. I think the JSON path i gave is not working.

What would be the right JSON path to count the number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually looks like that you receive XML document from DSS. That is why is not applicable json function to xml content.  I managed to get count of elements using script mediator

```
<script language="js">var dl = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::Datalist;
   var cnt = dl.length();
   mc.setProperty("cnt", cnt);
</script>
<log level="full">
    <property name="cnt" expression="get-property('cnt')"/>
</log>
```

as result a get property in body context with name "**cnt**" and value "**2**"

lets say you transform u xml message to json and get this json payload(perfectly valid)

```
{"DataCollection": [
    {"Datalist": {
            "partybranchid": 2127629166052452,
            "partybranchname": "other locations",
            "status": 1,
            "partybranchtype": -1,
            "partyid": 460077453499443,
            "partyname": "Yash Technologies Pvt Ltd",
            "ouid": -1,
            "organizationunitname": "NONE",
            "inchargeid": -1899999899,
            "sbuheadid": -1,
            "usercriteriaconfigid": 1187416899913503,
            "primarymail": "vikash@myunisoft.com"
        }
    },
    {"Datalist": {
            "partybranchid": 2545910581364239,
            "partybranchname": "DBPB001",
            "status": 1,
            "partybranchtype": 2299733851146138,
            "partyid": 2534954639984412,
            "partyname": "DBPRTY001",
            "ouid": 2538210579514587,
            "organizationunitname": "DBORG001",
            "inchargeid": 2540093122446574,
            "sbuheadid": 1209449655666077,
            "usercriteriaconfigid": 1187416899913503,
            "primarymail": "vikash@myunisoft.com"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Then JSONPATH expression

```
$.DataCollection.length
```

returns value length of array, in this case equal "2"

useful links

- Json validator http://jsonlint.com/
- JsonPath tester http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/

Or provide u payload in json format.

Comment: Hi this actually  working but i want to pass this value in the JSON payloadfactory mediator so how can i do that, instead of using script mediator is there any direct JSONpath to count the number of element.

Comment: Just get count of Datalist and then later pass message to JSON payload medator, then u will have property in body context with total number of Datalist item, and available in JSON payload mediator.

Comment: hi simar actually am looking to set a property with  JSONpath to get the count of Datalist elements so that i can pass this value in my JSON payload, u have any idea how to set this property with JSONpath

Comment: get-property('cnt') gets value 2  but this can be passed in XML payload but not in JSON payload,need to set a json property like <property name="cnt" expression="json-eval($.cnt)"/> like this.

Comment: AFAIK, you can not use JSONpath on XML document. There are two ways to get count.
1. First convert your XML document into JSON payload and then check for count using JSON Path 
2.Use XSLT/script to get the count of 'Datalist' and store in some property 
Then you can set that value into payload factory mediator using get-property('count'). A property value from XML can be used in both into XML and JSON. Please give a try.

Comment: I have tried as u suggested Deepak and and passed tha xml values in the JSON payload it helped me ,actually am looking for JSONpath to get count of the elements.

Comment: I have checked WSODSS documentation and find out, it supports payload in JSON format as well, starting from 3.2.0 version.